# Primefaces 7 doesnt display line break in datatable header

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, jboss7.x

Im running a webapplication JEE /JSF on Jboss 7.3.1. Cause of vulnerability issues we had to upgrade Primefaces 6.2 to 7.0. I doesnt go to 8.x.x cause of too much changes in code and effort to test for now.
Problem as follows : Im using <h:outputText> for display names, sometimes with html inside like <br/>.The linebreak will be displayed correctly for plain use in xhtml, but if that same <h:outputText> is in pf datatable header like this, the linebreak wont be displayed correctly.

```
<p:column id="#{cc.attrs.cid}actionColumn"
                  rendered="#{cc.attrs.tableController.actionColumnVisible}"
                  style="text-align: center; width:#{cc.attrs.tableController.actionColumnWidth.width}px;">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <!-- to do resource bundle -->
                <h:outputText id="#{cc.attrs.cid}actionHeader" value="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.action}" escape="false"/>
            </f:facet>
```

This is the way im building the string to disply :

```
res.getString("konfiguration.fahrzeugKonfiguration.standard")+"&lt;br/&gt;"+res.getString("konfiguration.fahrzeugKonfiguration.ansageSprache")
```

Same code leads to :
[doesnt breakLine in tableheader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zofOM.png)

Is that a bug in pf 7.0 or did i do something wrong ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried, setting _escape_ attribute to false? This would not escape HTML relevant characters and thus might produce the line break (haven't tried it myself, though).

Comment: I had <br/> with pf 6.2 and changed after upgrade to pf 7.0 cause <br/> wasnt working with <h:outputText>. And escape=false is set in my code snippet, scroll ->

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but what's the vulnerability that force you to upgrade to Primefaces 7.0?

Comment: So it works if you don't use a resource bundle? And it works on tomcat?

Comment: @WoAiNii inputTextarea: lack of user input validation (maxlength)

Comment: @Kukeltje The <br/> doesnt work either with plain String in datatable header. I tried to deploy application to tomcat but doesnt get it running cause of project structure, ear file